# Nifi expression language for jsonpath - string manipulation, split

Tags: apache-nifi

I'd like to manipulate values from two properties in the json using Nifi. I don't know how which functions are available to use in the EvaluateJsonPath processor in the Nifi. That's an example of json:

```
{
   "ensemblGeneId":"ENSG00000145982",
   "approvedName":"phenylalanyl-tRNA synthetase 2, mitochondrial",
   "hgncId":"HGNC:21062",
   "nameSynonyms":"\"iGb3 synthase\", \"isoglobotriaosylceramide synthase\"",
   "approvedSymbol":"FARS2",
   "ncbiGeneId":"10667",
   "symbolSynonyms":"IGBS3S, IGB3S"
}
```

I'd like to to treat values from nameSynonyms and symbolSynonyms properties, converting to array of string, like this:

```
"nameSynonyms":["iGb3 synthase", "isoglobotriaosylceramide synthase"],
"symbolSynonyms":["IGBS3S", "IGB3S"]
```

I think of using ReplaceText processor or EvaluateJsonPath. If I use the ReplaceText processor, I need to use some of this processor. I'd like to use multiple replace expressions once. Otherwise, using EvaluateJsonPath, I don't know how which expressions may be use to resolve it, may include split, replace, concat functions, and so on... But I don't know how to use these functions in the processor.

How it it more appropriate to use in this case? Is there another processor that could be use?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The json sample is not valid because of value for key `nameSynonyms`.

Comment: I agree. `"nameSynonyms":"iGb3 synthase", "isoglobotriaosylceramide synthase",` is not a key value format for json.

Comment: I made a mistake. I already updated the sample! Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do this with a combo of ReplaceText and JoltTransformJSON. I have attached screenshot of a [image].

First, I replace the escaped quotes in nameSynonyms with an empty string in the ReplaceText processor. Processor Configuration is  shown below [image]

Second, I use a jolt spec to convert nameSynonyms and symbolSynonyms to an array.
Jolt spec is below 

`[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "nameSynonyms": "=split(',',@(1,nameSynonyms))",
      "symbolSynonyms": "=split(',',@(1,symbolSynonyms))"
    }
}
]`

The output json is as in the screenshot[image]

Hope this helps and if so please accept the answer.